# Randomly assign color to instances within Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

I would like to give each instance (here a cube) **within a geometry node setup** a randomly assigned color. I have tried *Capture Attribute* but haven't had success with it so far.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, this question has already been asked a few times in different forms, but here is a variant that describes the current solution path with **Blender 3.2**:

[image]

This is where the `Store Named Attribute` node comes into play, with which you can store a color value per instance. This color value is then simply queried in the shader using the `Color Attribute` node.

Comment: This is actually clearer than the method that was linked in the comment. Thank you!

Comment: is it possible that this doesn't work in Cycles? I get colored cubes in Eevee but they are grey for Cycles..

Comment: @LennartVanderGoten I have updated the answer, sorry, was my mistake. If you want to make it work in *Eevee* and *Cycles* you would actually have to use the `Color Attribute` node in the shader here instead of `Attribute` to read the value for "color".

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm!

Comment: If you want to make it work in Blender 3.5.1 Cycles you must use other name than "color" for the attribute value.