# Data sharing between geometry nodes and shader through attributes not working

Tags: shaders, geometry-nodes, custom-attributes

When I share data between shader and geometry nodes through attributes (more concretely, I was sharing color of the object), it works perfectly, as seen on picture:

[image: It just works]

However, when I don't use the original geometry (eg. use `Cube` node), it stops working:

[image]

Why does it not work and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/268739/145249

Comment: You could try this too: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/270303/145249

Comment: That color attibute is for the original cube only, if you want add color to an instance, use the SET MATERIAL node in front of the instance and before the Output

Comment: Combination of @quellenform and Emir comments worked perfectly, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just to be able to mark the question as solved, here is a short answer to this from the comments:

To transfer a color attribute from *Geometry Nodes* to the *Shader*, a corresponding attribute must be created.

This can either be passed directly to the *Group Output* (as seen in your screenshot), or an attribute can be explicitly created with the node `Store Named Attribute`.

Here you have two options.

Either you create the attribute and read it in the shader with the node `Attribute`:

[image]

Or you create a *Color Attribute* beforehand, store your color there, and read this attribute with the node `Color Attribute`:

[image]

In addition, a material must be assigned to the created geometry with `Set Material`!